# How to clear the Webworkers Message Queue

Tags: javascript, timeout, message-queue, web-worker

I have a computationally expensive Webworker that is supposed to only work with the most recent data that was sent as a Message:

```
let nextEventData = null;
self.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
  if (running) {
    nextEventData = e;
    return;
  }
  running = true;
  costlyFunction(e);
})

let costlyFunction = (d) => {
  nextEventData = d;
  while (nextEventData != null){
    nextEventData = null;
    // Do something ASYNC with the data
  }
}
```

Apparently my Async function does still block my Worker in a way that the Messagequeue is not handled as intended and ALL messages trigger the 'costlyFunction'. Instead, I'm currently using a Timeout:

```
let nextEventData = null;
let timeout;
self.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
  if (running) {
    return;
  }
  clearTimeout(timeout)
  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    running = true;
    costlyFunction(e);
  }, 50)
})
```

Using a fixed timeout doesn't seem like the most elegant way since we are stalling the computation longer than necessary after the last message. So my question:

Is there a way to somehow 'clear' the Messagequeue and to only use the most recent data **without** artificially stalling the computation with a timeout?

Comment: Apparently, the only way to clear the Queue is to handle all messages received. Therefore, the EventListener needs to be as lightweight as possible using ```setTimeout(...)``` with a rather small time to wait. In my case 5ms are sufficient. Since this is very user/client setup specific it's still not a great solution but at least it works...